# Are rusty stains allowed to happen with hot dip galvanized steel construction?

Tags: metals, metalwork

I ordered a fence and the provider agreed to deliver it made from hot dip galvanized steel covered with powder painted finishing. The price was significantly bigger thank with the electro galvanization.

They started assembling the whole thing and I have spotted some worrying rust-like stains underneath the construction, on the insides of the C-shape profiles. Please see the pictures.

Am I being scammed? Can you tell, by mere pictures, if it's a hot dip or electro galvanized surface?

[image: Rust ?#1]
[image: Rust ?#2]
[image: Rust ?#3]
[image: Rust ?#4]

Please help. It cost a lot but I am afraid the provider is not honest with me.

**Update**
I have used sandpaper to remove the coating from a small part of the element. Here what I saw. Put some salty water on it, we'll see tomorrow.
[image: Sandpaper]

Also, on the other part of the element used a brush (don't know a type, toiled cleaning type I guess) and here are the effects before and after.

Before some brushing:
[image]
And after:
[image]

Some of the dark-red dust is gone but yellowish stains remained.
Look similar to what I spotted on some scraps from profiles with some holes in them (also, supposedly hot dip coated and powder painted).
[image: profile stains]

Also spotted some similar constructions in my town and they had technical holes in them (to prevent air bubbles and ex-/imploding of the element while hot dipping) and mine does not have them even almost identical to what I saw. Even more suspicious now...

Comment: You can tell by looking if it was galvanized but you also said it was powder coated on top of that so I'm not sure how you expect us to see through that. But if there's rust does that mean it's on top of the paint? How do you know it's not just dust?

Comment: @DKNguyen thank you for sharing your thoughts. I don't expect you to see through. I thought that maybe there are some characteristic signs of this process like droplets of zinc or something in the corners. The same way you could tell if it was welded, I guess.

As for the dust - that's a good point. I will use a brush to try getting rid of those stains and share the photos after that.  On the last picture it kinda looks like something sprinkled on top of the surface but on the top-left part of the profile you can see something like a little pitting, like the coating was missing there.

Comment: Since zinc does protect uncovered surfaces and a lot is at stake, you could get some scotch brite and rub away a patch on the steel. If you go slow you should see a progression from paint to something else (some kind of galvanization like the typical a speckled pattern or just something different than steel) then steel.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I'll record the process and share in case anyone's interested.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I have updated my post with some pictures. Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Really tough without being there and seeing the progression. To me it looks like there is none unless you encountered a change in between what is shown or have yet to encounter a change afterwards. You could take a piece of metal you know is galvanized and scrub away at that and see how difficult it is to wipe out the pattern to see if you inadvertently wiped it out while getting through the paint. Or you could paint over it and try sanding that to see if the speckle is clearly visible when you scrub through the paint.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say powder paint, but if you mean a powder coat that does not look like a powder coat. I imagine powder coating is very expensive since the entire thing must sit in an oven.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to make promises from a photo, but it is difficult to see any evidence of zinc coating. Not electrogalvanized, not hot dipped, possible a poor quality (thin) zinc rich coating ( paint).

Comment: Thank you for your input. Could you elaborate on what evidence there could be of the hot dipping (that's what I'm supposed to be paying for!) process? I'm looking at random pictures of hot dipped profiles and can't see anything obvious.

If I took a sample and damage it somehow can we tell then? Like if I ground it a bit with the sand-paper or something? I bet I can find some leftovers to experiment on.

Comment: Hot dip is usually glossy and has "spangle"  pattern, probably you can find spangle pattern on the net. And I expect a galvanizing failure ( loss of zinc) to appear as discrete spots ,not a general blush of rust.